# Image bring front using css

Tags: html, css

I am using the below code to view the product id. Using background image for each list. I want to bring image front and text go back.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
.addcart
{

}
 .addcart ul{
     list-style:none;
        }
 .addcart li{
     list-style:none;
          background-image:url(round.png);
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            height:45px;
            top:0px;
        }
        .addcart h3
        {
            font-size:24px; 
            font-weight:bold;
            padding:10px 0px 40px 10px; 
            color:#F00;
            z-index:400px;  
            position:relative;
        }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<ul class="addcart">
<li><span><h3>96</h3></span></li>
<li><h3>97</h3></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You cannot do that as you are setting image as background.

Comment: what exactly you want to achieve. Do you want to change the bullets or what?

Comment: I need to show the text also. But image in front and text in back.

Comment: use `<img>` tag inside `li`  `<li><h3><img src="round.png" />97</h3></li>`

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to hide the text, do this:

```
.addcart h3 {
    position : absolute;
    left     : -9999px;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PFMHr/

Answer (score 1):

You want text to go back? may I suggest you hide it instead with

```
display:none;
```

If this isnt a viable solution for your work, can you elaborate on the functionality?

Comment: That can lead to negative SEO backlash. Just something to be wary of.

Comment: I need to show the text also. But image in front and text in back.

Answer (score 0):

You could add on the .addcart li ?

`text-indent:-9999em;`

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best way is to just set that text's display property to **none** via Javascipt or jQuery whatever. No need to send it back. Or do you have any specific reason to send it back?

Answer (score 0):

z-index is not a property to be given in pixels, it shouild be

```
z-index: 400;
```

also, using a h3 this way is not optimal, I would use span instead; Anyway you are increasing font size so you don't need to relay on h3 for this.